# How can I ensure that multiple Laravel Listeners for the same event are executed and finished before starting the next one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, events, listener

I have a Laravel 5.7 (with PHP 7.2) application that uses events and listeners with Redis queues. I have some workers that consume the queue and execute the listeners.

this is my event and listeners interaction in the `EventServiceProvider` class:

```php
protected $listen = [
    SavedObject::class => [
        Listener1::class,
        Listener2::class,
        Listener3::class,
    ],
];
```

My problem is that I need that `Listener2` executes and finishes before `Listener3` is even executed. Laravel ensures that the listeners are executed in order, but if I have multiple workers, the `Listener2` is executed and before it's finished, another worker executes `Listener3` and it ruins everything.

How can I ensure that `Listener2` finishes before starting `Listener3` execution?
Maybe a way to execute all of the Listeners of the same event using the same worker to ensure that?

Comment: Why not call the subsequent listeners directly, from within the first one? If the functions  must be executed in exact sequence, then perhaps they are better off being contained within a single listener.

Comment: What is the best way to do that? because I don't want to create another Event class just to do that. Is there a way to call a listener inside another one?

Comment: As long as you don't queue the listeners, they will be executed sequentially, in the specified order.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "chain", when Listener1 is over fire Listener2 and then fire Listener3

```
Event::fire("Eventname", $attributes);
```

Comment: But I could need more than one event to do that, and that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Could you give me an example? It help me to understand better your task.

Comment: I think you need to make an Event chain, events are not sync with queues and should not be. If you come with Listeners name, i will write up an answer :)